# Checking for page templates in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, parent-child

I have a simple problem I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.  I have a child theme with a custom page template and I'm simply trying to check weather or not the template is in use.  Under normal circumstances, I would have just used the `is_page_template` function, however it doesn't seem to be working with child themes.  I've tried the following

```
if(is_page_template('template-custom-fullwidth.php')){
    //do something..
}
```

as well as

```
if(is_page_template(dirname(get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')).'/template-custom-fullwidth.php'){
    //do something..
}
```

Neiter works and I was hoping there is a more elegant solution than using `$_SERVER` to check for URLs.  I can't imagine there not being a function for this seeing as this seems like a common task.  I believe the problem is the difference between template and stylesheet directories.  Is it possible to use Wordpress to check for page templates located in a child theme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you use this code?

Comment: @MidhuN - I'm actually using the code within the functions.php file in my child theme, I'm trying to avoid modifying the parent theme as much as possible, but I think that's what the problem is.

Comment: You're not invoking it from a function called within the loop, are you? And you're doing it to process pages (in the WP sense, i.e. relatively static content), right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reference this WP Codex page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` instead. This should work:

```
is_page_template(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/template-custom-fullwidth.php')
{
    //do something..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue. One few trial and error noticed that if the conditional is kept inside the function it works. but if kept outside it does not.

```
function team_page_enqueue_style() {

    if ( is_page_template('page-team.php') ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'easy-responsive-tabs-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/easy-responsive-tabs.css', array(), NULL);
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'team_page_enqueue_style' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If is_page_template is used inside the loop try putting `wp_reset_query()` before call to is_page_template.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and solved it like this:

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` won't work cause it will show the url and you need the server full path, use `get_stylesheet_directory()`

If `is_page_template()` doesn't work you can use `get_page_template()` and compare

```
if(get_page_template() == (get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom-template.php')){
//your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [is_singular();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) it worked for my case as my template is a single post page template.

To use it, you need to specify the name of the template without the word `single-` and `.php`. For example, if the template file is `single-forest_of_trees.php`, then this should be the code:

```
if (is_singular( 'forest_of_trees' )) {
   // do something
}
```

it also allows an elegant way for multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is (in functions.php):

```
if (get_page_template_slug() == 'template-custom-fullwidth.php'){

// anything

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works for me in a child theme is accessing the global $template variable and comparing against it:

```
global $template;
if (basename($template) === 'template-custom-fullwidth.php') {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path from your theme's  folder:

```
if(is_page_template('page-templates/template-custom-fullwidth.php')){
//do something..
}
```